# Do I need to keep the Ascension expansion boxes as I have the original one?

Tags: expansions, storage, ascension

I have the original Ascension box with wooden separators (pictured below), what makes for a nice, long lasting storage for cards - I would say, a lot of them, as the separators seem quite empty holding only the original game cards.

I'm planning to buy a couple of expansions when travelling abroad, and given the original box and separators, I'm thinking about getting rid of the boxes and bringing home only the cards and manuals - this way I can bring more stuff with me.

Is this idea reasonable? Are there reasons to keep the other boxes (besides, maybe, space for several expansions)?

[image]

Comment: Your "Bonus" should be a separate question, so others with this same question would have an easier time finding it. (Among other reasons.)

Comment: @tsuma534: remove that part on the original question as this is already sort-of-answered at http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/22885/do-ascensions-small-box-expansions-work-well-with-the-other-big-boxes?rq=1 and http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/2434/17509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that version of Ascension has the [Broken Token Box Organizer](http://www.thebrokentoken.com/ascended-organizer/) (or similar) included, which should allow for most, if not all, of the expansions to fit into the one box.

The game normally comes with an insert that looks a [little different](https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic773006_lg.jpg).

As such you would not need to keep the additional expansion boxes if you have no desire to resell the game, or display the boxes.

Comment: Wow! That's the original inserts? The Brazilian version comes with a lot of zip bags and a paper division to fill up box space lol

Comment: My organizer seems quite inspired on that from Broken Token, but it also includes actual token boxes (not broken haha)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you sleeve all your cards you will need at least 2 boxes, almost 3

Answer (score 0):

The original box won't fit all the current expansions, there's just too many cards at this point, but no there is no good reason to keep the other boxes if you don't want them, they just take up space at that point. I kept mine, but that's personal preference there, my cards are currently all stored in 2 years of the special edition tins, and it already takes up both years full space.

It should be noted that you definitely need the rule books from each still, as you mentioned, since last I checked Stone Blade has yet to release a comprehensive rulebook (I have emailed asking for a PDF) and each new expansion adds new rules to the base game.

Comment: And even so, while not mandatory, it would be good to keep the new boards as well, right? I'll probably keep the big boxes and store the small expansions with the sets they're most playable with.

Comment: @igorsantos07 Fair point, all sets are playable together of course, though you do run into the downside of Stone Blade not offering an energy only buy so your decks end up energy light if you play with too many (I left the energy in from the original copy when I bought my year tin so I'd have double, made it better.)

Comment: But mixing too much sets might make your games seem a tad boring, because of the low chance of making good combos, wouldn't it?

Comment: @igorsantos07 It depends what you want from your game, some people want games where it is harder to combo out, since a particularly good combo just ends the game. I've had games even with 1000+ cards in the center deck where 90% of the cards ended in my deck because I could do a repeatable extra turn combo or had 5 copies of Adayu the serene due to copy effects so would draw 5 cards per enlightened I played.